# Update SQL Database with JSON

Tags: sql, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm receiving a JSON result in my ASP webapi SaveChanges action. I want to take that JSON string and convert it to an SQL Update string.

Just wondering if anyone knows what the best way to convert a JSON string to an SQL Update Query.

Here is an example of the JSON string I am receiving and the equivalent SQL:

```
[{"ContactID":3,"FirstName":"Tester","LastName":"Tester","DepartmentName":"Dept"}]
```

Which would equate to:

```
UPDATE Contact Set FirstName = 'Tester', LastName = 'Tester', DepartmentName = 'Dept' Where ContactID = 3
```

Currently I'm doing a pretty nasty for loop on a JArray to build the SQL update string. So if anyone has any other cleaner methods that would be great.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wrote a store procedure based on Phil's parseJSON function, it works and have not discovered any bugs yet.

[link to My code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945458/tsql-parse-json-string-to-update-table-please-check-and-advise-any-bugs)